# PHP have cURL return HTML as function return string instead of outputing to client

Tags: php, curl

After making two cURL requests the second request I want to capture the returned HTML and pass it back to the calling function as a string. Right now it instead outputs the HTML to the client. I've messed with `ob_end_clean()` and `ob_get_contents()` without success.

Here is what I currently have...

```
function stuff()
{
 //user/pass stuff omitted.

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookies);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"user=$cp_user&pass=$cp_pwd");
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,100020);

 ob_start();
 $f = curl_exec($ch);
 $h = curl_getinfo($ch);
 $p0 = explode('cpsess',$h['url']);
 $p1 = explode('/',$p0[1]);
 ob_end_clean();

 /***/
 ob_start();
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$q2a.$p1[0].$q2b);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_exec($ch);
 $r = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
 /***/

 curl_close($ch);

 return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
```

And then catch the returned content with

```
function stuff() {
    // function code before

    $r = curl_exec($ch);

    // function code after

    return $r;
}
```

Don't use any `ob_` functions for this because if the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is not set explicit to `true` or `1` curl won't return or print out any content from the request.